# Can't find MySQL data directory: my.cnf doesn't contain basic settings

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to follow the instructions on https://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/. I found the `my.cnf` file in `etc/mysql` as in the example, but to my surprise it doesn't contain any Basic Settings, only the following:

```
# Copyright (c) 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301 USA

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

I would also expect lines with `user =`, `datadir =`, etc. Is MySQL somehow not set up correctly?

Comment: look at those last two lines... and ponder for a while on what `includedir` implies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)'s comment, I did a little search and found the same question answered on Askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/699903/why-etc-mysql-my-cnf-is-empty.

To reiterate, the `includedir` lines are saying that **additional** configuration files (.cnf in this case) can be found in the directories listed.